# Search in jsonb and array combination in postgres with rails4 stored_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a model called Event, where I have stored_accessor "list" (stored like  `data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key1", "value"=>"value1"}]}`).

I need to make a search query o

```
#<Event id: "1", title: "HHHH", description: nil, data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key1", "value"=>"value1"}, {"key"=>"key2", "value"=>"value2"}]}, created_at: "2017-04-14 21:06:22", updated_at: "2017-04-20 10:36:08">
#<Event id: "2", title: "HHHH", description: nil, data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key1", "value"=>"value1"}]}, created_at: "2017-04-14 21:06:22", updated_at: "2017-04-20 10:36:08">
#<Event id: "3", title: "HHHH", description: nil, data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key11", "value"=>"value11"}, {"key"=>"key12", "value"=>"value12"}]}, created_at: "2017-04-14 21:07:22", updated_at: "2017-04-20 10:37:08">
#<Event id: "4", title: "HHHH", description: nil, data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key111", "value"=>"value111"}, {"key"=>"key112", "value"=>"value112"}]}, created_at: "2017-04-14 21:08:22", updated_at: "2017-04-20 10:38:08">
```

I have a serach params like

```
1) {'key'=> 'key1', 'value'=> 'value1'}
2) ["key"=>"key1", "value"=>"value1"}, {"key"=>"key2", "value"=>"value2"}]
```

In first case, it should return `Event` id `1` and `2`.

In second case, it should return `Event id 1`. (event if return `1 and 2` both could be acceptable).

I am not sure with json and array combination.
Please help.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)? Did you try something?

Comment: yes I know about, but my attribute is bit nested like `data: {"list"=>[{"key"=>"key1", "value"=>"value1"}, {"key"=>"key2", "value"=>"value2"}]}`, data -> list -> {key, value}(then check the hash)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with PostgreSQL jsonb's operator `@>`. Also you need to write the full path for search params: `{'list' => [{'key'=> 'key1', 'value'=> 'value1'}]}`. Try this code:

```
to_contain1 = {'list' => [{'key'=> 'key1', 'value'=> 'value1'}]}
to_contain2 = {'list' => [{'key'=> 'key2', 'value'=> 'value2'}]}

Event.
  where("data @> ?", to_contain1.to_json})
# returns events 1 & 2

Event.
  where("data @> ?", to_contain1.to_json).
  where("data @> ?", to_contain2.to_json)
# returns event 1
```